# why crontab requires shell path sometimes?

Tags: shell, cron

I am working solaris 10 and using bash shell.

I have a shell script which I run manually it works fine.

`/shellscriptfullpath.sh`

I have added the same to crontab and it stopped from working.

later I have added the shell path as first command and tested,it started working.

`#!/bin/bash`

some of my scripts run without shell path also.

what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add in cron the script gets executed in default shell (mostly csh or ksh)
To avoid this you have to add the first line saying which shell you need.

Comment: for some scripts I did not add the path still they r running.

Comment: If you have used some shell specific syntax then you will face problems. Example arrays are supported in bash but not in csh. Also way you export a variable in bash and csh are different

Comment: A script without a shebang (`#!...`) is executed by `/bin/sh`, which may or may not be a symlink to bash or ksh. This is implemented in the kernel, not by cron.